# ObjectInputStream Handling classNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, io

I have an issue while reading the data from a file using objectInputStream. Please find the code below

```
File file = new File("model.pst")       
if (file.exists()) {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            input = (List<GlobalModel>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
```

I got to know from the ObjectOutputStream http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html docs, that while writing the object to the file, he default serialization mechanism for an object writes the class of the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient and non-static fields.I have an issue where the class name has been changed after writing the object to the file and when I use the above code to read the values, its throwing a classNotFound exception. I would like to know if there is a way, I can handle this exception, i.e once it comes to the exception block, can I replace the classname in the object that is being read to the new class name and make it work ?

Please Assist. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Moral: don't change the class name after serialising instances of it. Don't change *anything* unless you have read and understood the Object Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification. There are many things you *can* change. That isn't one of em.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself but it should be possible to replace a class by another by making a subclass of object input stream and overriding the resolveClass method, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#resolveClass(java.io.ObjectStreamClass)